# Documenting sqlalchemy classes using sphinx when module requires setup before import

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-sphinx

I would like to document a set of sqlalchemy database classes.  I have followed this type of logic when coding these classes.  In db.**init**.py, I have an init_model() function that establishes a database connection and binds it to the declarative_base.  I then import that declarative_base in my db.objects.py and use it to autoload the tables from the database instance.  Unfortunately, when I try to autodoc the db.objects, sphinx tries to do the import of db.objects and finds an unbound metadata since init_model was not called first.  Any suggestions as to what to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael Bayer was nice enough to offer this potential solution:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sqlalchemy/lLR233kwHFw/discussion